# BarLengend for GeoStyling["ReliefMap"]

Tags: legending, geographics

I would like to add a `BarLegend` for the elevation values used by the `GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["ReliefMap"]` option of `GeoGraphics`.

Here's my code:

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoMarker[{5.52, -73.08}]  }, GeoBackground ->  GeoStyling["ReliefMap", ColorFunction -> ColorData["LightTerrain"]],  GeoRange -> 8000 ]
```

I would like to produce the `BarLegend` giving the scale of the terrain elevations used in the background of my `GeoGraphics`.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

```
minmax = QuantityMagnitude @ MinMax @ 
  GeoElevationData[GeoDisk[GeoPosition[{5.52, -73.08}], 8000]];
legend = BarLegend[{"LightTerrain" , minmax}];

Legended[GeoGraphics[{GeoMarker[{5.52, -73.08}]}, 
  GeoBackground ->  GeoStyling["ReliefMap", ColorFunction -> "LightTerrain" ],  
  GeoRange -> 8000], legend]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you sooo much. Cheers!